# Yii - Defining relation in model two levels through

Tags: yii, relationship

I'm wondering if it's possible in a model to define a relation through two tables.

I would like to start from Picture model and to get relative Place model.

I have Picture model with :

```
id | event_id
```

I have Event model with :

```
id | place_id
```

I have Place model with :

```
id
```

I know I can do something like that : `$model->event->place;`

But I'm just wondering if it's possible.

My goal is to create a recursiveEncode method and to just pass "place" in relation in order to get well formated JSON.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Picture extends CActiveRecord {
...
    public function relations () {
        return array(
            'event' => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Event', 'event_id' ),
            'place' => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Place', array('place_id'=>'id'), 'through' => 'event' ),
        );
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I did not know that my own used word "through" was a keyword in Yii. 
Works well ! For others, be careful of order in array, the good syntaxe is : 'place_id' => 'id'

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as possible with `Yii` by using `with` and `through` in relation. As `Yii`'s official document:

**through**

> name of the model's relation that will be used as a bridge when getting related data. Can be set only for HAS_ONE and HAS_MANY.

**with**

> string|array, a list of child related objects that should be loaded together with this object. Note, this is only honored by lazy loading, not eager loading.

**Example**:

```
    'author'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'author_id'),
    'comments'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'post_id', 'with'=>'author')
```

Then, you can access to related object with `.`. For example `parent.child`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail